# Understanding objects

Tags: javascript, object

So as I'm learning Javascript I do intend to ask a ton of questions

normally I understand how variable assignments work but this code is a bit confusing why obj[b] = "hello world"?

```
var obj = {
  a: "hello world", 
  b: 42
}; 

var b = "a" ;

obj[b]; // "hello world" < why is this Hello world?
obj["b"]; // 42
```

Comment: Because you are accessing the `a` property...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var obj = {
  a: "hello world", 
  b: 42
}; 

var b = "a" ; // this creates a new variable with string value "a"

obj[b]; // this references the object property having the string value of 
        // variable b, which is "a"
```

Comment: I see, that's very interesting thank you. How does it know that b = "a"; could be referring to a inside the object or it doesn't matter?. that's a cool trick

Comment: Object keys are referenced as strings (with quotation marks) or as variables (without).

Answer (score 2):

`obj[b]` is equivalent to `obj['a']` since you assigned the variable `b` the value of `'a'`

In JavaScript, you can access object properties like an array using bracket notation (mentioned by Andrew) as above or using the dot notation `obj.a`.

Answer (score 2):

The [] notation allow to access properties/methods in an object dynamically.

Let say you have this dictionnary :

```
var dict = {
  foo : "bar",
  hello : "world"
};

function access(obj, property){
  return obj[property];
};

console.log(access(dict, "hello"));//world
```

You cannot do that with dot notation.